# Quickblox for android and web using PHP as backend

Tags: quickblox

I was thinking of using the quickblox for my chat requirement.

We want to build a 1-1 chat between a user and admin. User will be logged in from the android and admin will be logged in from the web. We want the functionality for the user to chat with an admin person. Our backend code base is in PHP and both the android and web talks to the backend with rest APIs.
Some can please help me out on where should I start my development from. Can you share any sample code or tutorial to get me started with, it would be really helpful?

Answer (score 2):

It may be solve like this

For PHP admin side

1. First you need to create the dialog for all the user
2. Then for selected user you will call the [Retrieve_messages](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Retrieve_messages) api for getting all the user
3. For sending the message you have to call  [Create_message](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Create_message)

Ref : [QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat)

---

For android they have their own SDK for sending and getting the message 
[Android SDK](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android)